# Jinja Environment is not supporting absolute paths

Tags: python, jinja2

Setting the jinja_env to a particular directory, relative paths from that directory work, while absolute paths even within that directory don't. 
For eg:

```
j2_env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('/path/to/a_dir'))
```

Assuming the above code line,

```
j2_env.get_template('/path/to/a_dir/abc/abc.yaml').render()
```

throws exception:jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound while

```
j2_env.get_template('abc/abc.yaml').render()
```

works.

Can anyone explain this peculiarity?

Also, what is the pythonic solution? should i splice the absolute path and pass the relative path?

Comment: Did you try logging `os.path.abspath("abc/abc.yaml")`? Does it match your absolute path?

Comment: yes, of course. The absolute path is the absolute path of the file, and relative path is the absolute path split to the directory. No silly mistakes there! I am making it work by splitting the absolute path itself.

Comment: [This section of the docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#jinja2.FileSystemLoader) says that you can have multiple paths listed in the `FileSystemLoader`.  If you're going to use both absolute and relative paths, then what about giving it the root directory as a second path option?  Otherwise, what it's probably trying to do is append your absolute path to the path you already specified, which of course won't exist.